# How to hide get requests from express API?

Tags: node.js, api, express, request, backend

I have a question because I'm new in this.. I have website that showing products for guests. This website using API from backend that works via express.js and mongodb. The problem is client website have a dashboard where I can see all orders that guests are made. But i wouldn't  my guests can see the orders if they are type server request like "server/api/getorderlist/ and all orders just show  to them in json. How can I fix that?

Comment: I Found that thing is called CORS. But now the question is how to turn on this feature on my backend?

Comment: You can check is the user is admin 
If admin response with the orders data if not response with 401 unauthorized